# Which elements are concerned with the second parameter?

Tags: css

For example in this css :

```
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Which **li** elements are concerned in this css : direct child of the **ul** element , or all grandchilds of the **ul** element ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "second parameter". CSS doesn't have a concept of parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This selector is targeting every `ul` element, that is a direct child of a hovered `li` element, which in turn is a descendant (in any level) of a `ul` element that has a class `.dropdown`

Something like:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
   <!-- ... -->
   <!-- any level of descendant -->
       <li> <!-- hovered -->
          <ul> <!-- this will be targeted -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Example below effects all li's that are decendants of the ul.dropdown

```
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Example below only effects the direct children of the ul.dropdown

```
ul.dropdown > li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```